# cannot get id from table when updating

Tags: mysql

I cannot undestand
I`m using mysql

it is my query

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
update `accounts` as A
inner join `company` as C on C.Email = 'shalvasoft@gmail.com'
SET A.username = 'shaliapin777',
A.company_id = C.id,
C.cat = (select id from category where name = 'sdbjn'),
C.ContactName = 'shalva'
where A.email_code = 'edfwe4r64fd65ew46fd45' ;
```

everithing is working except
A.company_id = C.id
this line
so I can not get right id

can you help me???

Comment: everithing is working except A.company_id = C.id what do you mean ?

Comment: First: please tag questions with actually appropriate tags. This has nothing whatsoever to do with PHP. Next, please explain what it is you're trying to achieve. Your query looks very very complicated, and I'm sure can be made quite a bit easier.

Comment: what type of errors you are getting ?

Comment: We also don't understand why you're using mysql ;)

Comment: what is your sample input and output? And plz explain the purpose of your query. It will help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change values in two separate tables without specifying how those tables are related. It looks like you're getting your primary keys mixed up.

In order for this to work, you need to specify a proper `ON` condition for the `INNER JOIN`. For example, if the primary key of the `company` table is the `id` column:

```
UPDATE
    accounts as A
    INNER JOIN company as C ON C.id = A.company_id
SET
    ...
WHERE
    accounts.email_code = '...'
```

Comment: yes I understand
but I need to write accounts -->  id in company --> company_id

and if I will use C.id = A.company_id in ON statement
it will`not write

as I know 'ON' statement in 'INNER JOIN' is using as 'WHERE' in standart statement

ex.
select C.name from company as C,accounts as A where C.id = A.company_id